# how to understand the typical python two sum

Tags: python, dictionary, if-statement

This is a python interview question, the goal is to find 2 values that add up to the target value.

Attached is the solution.

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
target = 11

def solution(nums, target):
    d = {}
    for i, num in enumerate(nums):
        m = target - num
        if m in d:
            return [d[m],i]
        else:
            d[num]=i
            
solution(a,target)
```

I don't understand that since d is an empty `dict`, why will the attached code return the correct answer? How to properly understand the following `if m in d` statement?

```
if m in d:
    return [d[m],i]
else:
    d[num]=i
```

Comment: What you are seeing is a hash table implementation in Python. d is your hashtable, as you iterate, you keep adding your sum (i.e target - current number) to it with its position. When you find that you have a match, you return back the sum, and the position.

Comment: `if m in d` gives whether `m` is one of the keys in `d`. If it's there, you get the value against `m` from `d` if not, you create element in `d`

Comment: The answer to your question: Initially `d` is empty, but you fill it gradually as you go along.

Comment: I assume you have a typo here: instead of `m = tar - num` I assume you should have `m = target- num`

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
tar = 11

def solution(nums, target):
    d = {}
    for i, num in enumerate(nums):
        m = tar - num
        if m in d:
            return [d[m],i]
        else:
            d[num]=i
            
solution(a,tar)
```

What this is doing is iterating over each number in the list, finding the value needed to make it add up to the target number, and seeing if that number has already appeared by checking the dictionary.

If it hasn't, then it adds the current number to the dictionary as a key, and the index as its value. As it runs, the dictionary will contain each previous number in the list and their indexed.

When it finds that the number it needs to meet the target is in  the dictionary, it returns its index, as well as the index of the current number.